# How do I delete a row in my database using this method?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, crud, delete-row

It's been a while since I've tried programming something. I've been practicing basic CRUD on a DGV and database. I've got my "ADD/CREATE" function working, but my delete doesn't seem to work.

here's a screenshot:

[image]

EDIT:
Posting code here; this is my working ADD/CREATE function:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connectionstring = "server=" + server + ";" + "database=" + database +
        ";" + "uid=" + uid + ";" + "password=" + password + ";";
        con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from testdatabase", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        testTable1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        con.Close();

   // now instead of these next 4 lines
        DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        row[0] = tbID.Text;
        row[1] = tbName.Text;
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
   // ds.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(testTable1.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
   // is what i used to delete
   // what did i do wrong?

        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
        da.Update(ds);
        ((DataTable)testTable1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();

    }
```

Comment: Please post code inline. Avoid external resources if possible.

Comment: Why don't you simply copy/paste that block of code here?

Comment: Use ConnectionStringBuilder class instead of string concatenation.

Comment: This is the code that adds a new row to your grid. Not the code that tries to delete a row. Do you have a btnDelete_Click code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a row following a button click you could follow this pseudocode.

- First you check if there is a current row selected in the grid,
- If you found one then get the value from the cell where the primary
  key for the database table is stored. (Here I assume that this cell
  is the first one in the row and refers to the column ID in the
  database table)
- With that data open the connection, prepare the DELETE command with
  parameters and call ExecuteNonQuery to phisycally remove the row from
  the database table.
- After that you could remove the current row from the grid and inform
  the underlying datasource that the operation is
  complete.(AcceptChanges)

  ```
  private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // No row to delete?
      if(testTable1.CurrentRow == null)
           return;
      // Get the cell value with the primary key
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(testTable1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value)

      // Start the database work...
      connectionstring = .....;
      using(con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
      using(cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM testdatabase where id = @id", con))
      {
          con.Open();
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          // Fix the grid removing the current row
          testTable1.Rows.Remove(testTable1.CurrentRow);

          // Fix the underlying datasource 
          ((DataTable)testTable1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
      }
  }
  ```